# How can I get google to index my sitemap?

Tags: http, url, robots.txt, google-search-console

My sitemap is being: "Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag" - No: 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' http header but I have checked the code for all URLs submitted and looked in the HTTP headers using F12 and I cannot find any mention of ´no index´ or the X-Robots-Tag itself. Any ideas where the ´no index´ or ´X-Robots-Tag´might be?

https://theenglishcentremadrid.com/es/sitemap.xml
I've already looked in F12 under 'Network' and 'Headers' for the X'Robots-Tag and I´ve looked at the code for all 5 pages.

https://search.google.com/search-console/inspect?resource_id=https%3A%2F%2Ftheenglishcentremadrid.com%2Fes%2F&id=pil7wrQGCqosrtgPA2fF5g&alt_id=Yo6GYatGeqRN0PK613Ybhg&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It’s standard header for sitemaps (and you can’t remove it) because they aren’t shown in google index (their self URLs). Similar is for robots.txt. So, it isn’t cause of your issue.

The sitemap should have a X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow as you do not want Google to show the sitemap page in search results. The follow is what allows Google to process the links in the sitemap for inclusion in search results.